# How to expose Docker volumes to my local machine using KiteMatic interface

Tags: python, macos, docker, tensorflow, kitematic

Playing around with TensorFlow on my Mac, I'm using KiteMatic to run "temsorflow:latest" docker. I have some Python examples that I want to run on my local machine. Basically I want to be able to `import tensorflow as tf`, but since this library exists on my docker I need to somehow expose this folder out.

According to [KiteMatic documentations](https://kitematic.com/docs/managing-volumes/):

> Kitematic exposes a container’s volume data under
>   `~/Kitematic/<container's name>/`

but I couldn't see it there.

What am I missing?